# CGI in Java - Legacy but interesting (for educational purposes)

Tags: java, apache, iis, cgi, cgi-bin

I folks:

I  know that CGI is jurassic and before all of you call me lunatic, I must say that this question is only for EDUCATIONAL PURPOSES (in real cases I use JSP).

I'm trying to code a "Hello World" CGI in Java, and I'm unsucessful.

So I try the same job in C#. 
Both programs (C# and Java) are totally equal (line by line). The C# works and the Java don't.

Here's the code in C#:

```
  

    namespace CGI_CSharp  
    {  
        class Program  
        {  
            static void Main(string[] args)  
            {  
                Console.WriteLine("Content-Type: text/html\n"); // the extra "\n" is needed    
                Console.WriteLine("<html>");  
                Console.WriteLine("<head>");  
                Console.WriteLine("<title>CGI - C#</title>");  
                Console.WriteLine("</head>");  
                Console.WriteLine("<body>");  

                Console.WriteLine("<h1>Hello World !</h1>");  

                Console.WriteLine("</body>");  
                Console.WriteLine("<html>");  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

In the browser URL I wrote: **http://localhost/CGI_CSharp.exe** and BINGO! The C# code WORKS !

Now the same code in Java:

```
  

    public class CGI_Java  
    {  
        public static void main(String[] args)   
        {  
            System.out.println ("Content-Type: text/html\n");  
            System.out.println ("<html>");
            System.out.println ("<head>");  
            System.out.println ("<title>CGI - Java</title>");  
            System.out.println ("</head>");  
            System.out.println ("<body>");  

            System.out.println ("<h1>Hello World !</h1>");  

            System.out.println ("</body>");
            System.out.println ("</html>");  
        }  
    }
```

Now I've tried the URL:

**http://localhost/java.exe%20CGI_Java**

(as you know, the %20 is the space => (http://localhost/java.exe CGI_Java)

I get:

**HTTP 404.0 - Not Found**

So, I try again, now with a batch file (CGI_Java.bat) with a single line of text:

**java.exe CGI_Java** (content of the CGI_Java.bat)

And now, I try the URL:

**http://localhost&/CGI_Java.bat**

Now the browser shows:

**C:\inetpub\wwwroot>java.exe CGI_Java**

This is the prompt followed by the command I wrote in the batch file.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What server are you using?

Is `java.exe` on the path for the server?

(Note that if you alter the environment variable for the path you will have to restart the server for it to pick up the changes).

Comment: I ran these two examples in both IIS 7 and Apache. C# run in both servers and Java did not ran in any of them.